# How to be sure for deleting Google account instead of Gmail product

Tags: gmail, google-account

A while ago I wanted to delete whole Google account(because it's recovery mail was a custom domain, and this domain is not used anymore so I don't want new owner of domain to recover this Google account). And I deleted account, but today my friend said that "you may be deleted only Gmail service and someone can login with alternate mail, so be sure that you completely deleted Google account not just Gmail".

When I try to login with ....@gmail.com and it says "This account was deleted". So how can I be sure that whole account has deleted or I just deleted Gmail account.

Edit: It's not a work/company account, it's an ordinary Google account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to https://myaccount.google.com/preferences?pli=1#deleteservices to delete your account, there is an option there to delete services<sup>1</sup> instead of your whole account. But it's a separate process. You'd know if you simply removed Gmail from your account.

A Gmail account *is* a Google account, so if you're trying to sign in and it's telling you the account is deleted, it's deleted.

Further, after 2-4 weeks, a deleted account is completely unrecoverable (short of a court order, and even then is probably a lost cause).

I don't think you have anything to worry about.

---

<sup>1</sup> You can delete Google+, YouTube, and/or Gmail from your account separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i search some and i find out that you can login your google account with "myname@gmail.com" even if you delete your gmail service(you just cant use mailbox and can't receive e-mails but your username is permanent so you can use it to login) this is true? Also now it  says "couldn't find your google account" so i think my account is deleted permanently not just gmail because if it was gmail, i could be able to login with myname@gmail.com instead of  "couldn't find your google account" , right?